# get mysql views associated table name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know that VIEW in mysql is like a virtual table that is associated to a REAL table in a database. My question is this, how do I find out which table that a Mysql View is associated with using codes? Is there like a php or sql function that can get me that?

Thank you

**NOTE** : I just want the NAME of the table associated with the view

Comment: Views are necessarily associated with just one table.

Answer (score 1):

I believe SHOW CREATE VIEW is the function you are looking for...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-view.html

Comment: Not bad, but it would be nice if I could get just the name of the table without having to do some regular expression to extract it from the result of SHOW CREATE VIEW or something ;)

Comment: Well a view could be many tables, or not a table at all, so I believe you don't have much option.  Where I work we have some of the most complicated views you've ever seen, to ask a human which table they 'originate' from would be difficult, let alone a RegEx =/.